# Cancel jquery button.click on MVC ValidationMessageFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have an MVC solution that is using @Html.ValidationMessageFor along with a $('.btn').click() function to display a simple "Loading..." dialog.  I would like to cancel this click() function action if the form validation fails.  I have looked into the jquery.validation.unobtrusive library (and included it in my solution) and am currently attempting to do a check as follows.

```
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        if ($(this).validate().valid()) {
            $("#initialWaitTableLoad").fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

This validation check does not work and is still executing the fadeIn() method.  How can I prevent this action from occurring on validation failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to check a form's validity when a button is clicked, you would use the `.valid()` method within your click handler and attach `.valid()` to your `form`, not the button, as you had done.

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    if ($('#myform').valid()) { // test validity of the form
        $("#initialWaitTableLoad").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:

`$('#myform')` is simply my generic example above.   Inspect the DOM and use whatever jQuery selector you wish that targets this particular form.

Comment: FWIW, I would also need to add the form name to my @Html.BeginForm(..., new { name = "myform" })

Comment: @McArthey, or simply use whatever jQuery selector you wish to properly target this form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for validity on the form, not the button. In your case $(this) is referring to the button that was just clicked. If possible, edit your function to run on form submission rather than button click.

```
$('#myform').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $("#initialWaitTableLoad").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: You would not want to capture the `submit()` event because the plugin is already doing that automatically.

Comment: Thanks.  I had this straight in my code but all the attempts at resolving my issue had me mixed up.  I appreciate the reminder.